# Ionic tabs navigation issue

Tags: angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I'm using both of the Ionic framework and IU router to make a better navigation for you my first web application.

Here a simple architecture so you can easily understand the structure :

[image]

The problem I'm facing is that i'm not able to keep the state when navigating between tabs. for example. when I go to the next tab and click on next view and Press return, then I navigate to the first button, and when I go back to the second tab, I don't see the same state I left.

I can't resolve this problem.

here is a DEMO : [PLUNKER DEMO + CODE](http://plnkr.co/edit/DNT9TTpS0HdaNShkZjSW?p=preview)

and this is my states code :

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {


$stateProvider



    .state('live.today', {
  url: '/today',
  views: {
    today: {
      templateUrl: 'today_live.html',

    }
  }
})

 .state('live.yesterday', {
  url: '/yesterday',
  views: {
    yesterday: {
      templateUrl: 'yesterday_live.html'
    }
  }
})

 .state('live.tomorrow', {
  url: '/tomorrow',
  views: {
    tomorrow: {
      templateUrl: 'tomorrow_live.html'
    }
  }
})



 .state('match.composition', {

  url: '/composition',
  views: {
    view: {
      templateUrl: 'composition.html'
    }
  }
})

 .state('match.resume', {
    cache: false,
  url: '/resume',
  views: {
    view: {
      templateUrl: 'resume.html'
    }
  }
})

 .state('live', {

  url: '/live',
  views: {
    live_view: {
      templateUrl: 'live.html'
    }
  }
})

.state('match', {
    cache: false,
  url: '/match_details',
  views: {
    live_view: {
      templateUrl: 'match_details.html'
    }
  }
})

.state('news', {
    cache: false,
  url: '/news',
  views: {
    news: {
      templateUrl: 'news.html'
    }
  }
})




$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/live/today');


})
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for providing a demo and image. But I don't get your problem exactly? What is your desired behaviour?

Comment: The problem I'm facing is that i'm not able to keep the state when navigating between tabs. for example. when I go to the next tab and click on next view and Press return, then I navigate to the first button, and when I go back to the second tab, I don't see the same state I left.

Comment: For me your demo is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found a solution, which is to add " `<ion-content> </ion-content>` to the file where I have three tabs (live.html).

You can take a loot at the updated demo for someone who have the same complicated views architecture